# Probabilistic bounds of random polynomials

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

This is follow-up question to my previous question about the expected number of roots .
I am considering a random polynomial given by $$p(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i$$,
where each coefficient } $a_i$  is drawn independently from a Gaussian distribution.
For a given real number } $r > 0$, I am interested in  the probability
that all roots of  $p(z)$  lie within the circle of radius  $r$  in the complex plane
Any insights or references on this topic would be greatly appreciated
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with Theorems 4.1 and 4.2 in [1]. A statement of Theorem 4.2 is as follows: if $\nu_n(B(r))$ is the number of zeros within the disk $B(r)$ of radius $r$ when the degree is $n$, then the expected proportion of zeros inside the disk of radius $e^{-s/(2n)}$ is
$$
\lim_n E\Big[\frac{\nu_n(B(e^{-s/(2n)}))}{n}\Big]
= \frac{(1-e^{-s}(1+s))}{s(1-e^{-s})} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{s}{12} + o(s).
$$
The paper also explains why studying the proportion of roots inside the disk allows by symmetry to study the roots outside the disk, see (1.7)-(1.8).

[1]: Shepp, L.A. and Vanderbei, R.J., 1995. The complex zeros of random polynomials. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, pp.4365-4384.

Comment: What is $s$? Also, there are some typos in the formula. No matter where I put the missing closing bracket, the asymptotic expansion does not work out.

Comment: Many thanks: a closing bracket was missing in the numerator. The disk radius is $\exp(-s/(2n))$. Wolfram agrees with the expansion https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+of+%281-exp%28-x%29%281%2Bx%29%29%2F%28x%281-exp%28-x%29%29%29+at+x%3D0

Comment: Sorry, you’re right, now I see where I made an error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the beautiful reference.However,what you mentioned gives us the expected proportion of roots in a disc of certain radius,I am interested in the probability of a certain disc bounding all the roots

Comment: Theorem 4.1 in the same reference would give that the expected number of roots outside of the disk of radius $1/r$ for any $r<1$ stay constant as $n\to+\infty$. I had overlooked your exact question about the extreme value of the largest root in absolute value, for which these results are not conclusive.